# How to get Value of a custom field task in CSOM Project Server

Tags: c#, csom, ms-project, project-server

I am working on a console application for project server. Atm I can read the name and work percent of each task assined to the project. Each task has a custom field with an unique id. [It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Qer.png)

How do I get the value of the unique id? e.g. the 84

Here is my code to list the task name and work percent:

```
var projColl = projContext.LoadQuery(projContext.Projects
                .Where(p => p.Name == projectName)
                .Include(
                    p => p.Name,
                    p => p.Tasks,
                    p => p.Tasks.Include(
                        t => t.Name,
                        t => t.PercentComplete,
                        t => t.CustomFields
                      )
                    )
                 );



        projContext.ExecuteQuery();
        PublishedProject theProj = projColl.First();
        PublishedTaskCollection taskColl = theProj.Tasks;
        PublishedTask theTask = taskColl.First();
        CustomFieldCollection LCFColl = theTask.CustomFields;
        Dictionary<string, object> taskCF_Dict = theTask.FieldValues;

        int k = 1;    //Task counter.
        foreach (PublishedTask t in taskColl)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}.  {1, -15}       {2,-30}{3}", k++, t.Name, t.PercentComplete);

        }
```

I tried to use`Console.WriteLine("\t{0}.  {1, -15}       {2,-30}{3}", k++, t.Name, t.PercentComplete,t.CustomFields);`

but I only get

> Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.CustomFieldCollection

I also know the InternalName of the customfield if that helps

EDIT: I added [this exsample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Project-CSOM-Read-Local-CustomFields/blob/master/Project-CSOM-Read-Local-CustomFields/Program.cs) but I only get the values of the first row.
Any idea how to loop for every row?

Comment: You are only getting values from the first row because `LCFColl` is defined as the custom fields of `theTask` not the variable `t` that you use inside your loop. Start with moving the declaration of `LCFColl` inside your task loop: `CustomFieldCollection LCFColl = t.CustomFields;`.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Now I just have to somehow get the one particular custom field

Comment: Got it to work as I want. Thank you!

Comment: Great. I moved the comment to an answer so you can accept/mark it as the best answer. This way, it can be useful to other people who search for answered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting values from the first row because `LCFColl` is defined as the custom fields of the object variable `theTask` not the variable `t` that you use inside your loop. Move the declaration of `LCFColl` inside your task loop:

```
   foreach (PublishedTask t in taskColl)
   {

      CustomFieldCollection LCFColl = t.CustomFields;
      foreach (CustomField cf in LCFColl)
      {
          // do something with the custom fields
      }

      Console.WriteLine("\t{0}.  {1, -15}       {2,-30}{3}", k++, t.Name, t.PercentComplete);

   }
```